# Shortcut to a shortcut in Windows

Tags: windows, file, shortcut

I have a script that regularly creates a new folder on the network and saves files to a folder. When this script is run, it creates a shortcut to the folder just created.

What I really want is for all my users to be able to have a shortcut on each of their desktops that points to the most recent folder.

I'd thought I'd be able to provide them with a shortcut that points to the shortcut generated in the script. Unfortunately, Windows won't allow me to have a shortcut to a shortcut.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious alternative would be to use NTFS junctions. As far as I can tell, there's no problem with junctions to junctions.